# Not able to run Visual Studio Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hi I don't know what I did, when I try to run visual studio project by pressing F5, I can see only loading symbol in browser but not displaying anything. When I checked whats going on, I got to know it is running on IIS Express and not on ASP.net development server. 
What changes I should do to make my project to run on ASP.NET development server?

Comment: Try right clicking on the web project and selecting Debug -> Start new instance. What happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties of your web project you can see the start options which has a server option.

Also if you right click your web project you can see option to use IIS express or dvelopment server.

Comment: This thing worked. I changed my server option in properties window to development server. God I was worried that something terrible happened.:)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't worry , this is not big issue** .

Just open your `csproject` file into  notepad.

And find this line in your `csproject`

```
<UseIISExpress>True</UseIISExpress>
```

Then change True to false

```
<UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
```

And save that ,then you can run your project .